# css-what npm vulnerabilities react native

Tags: react-native

In my react native application i am getting css-what vulnerabilities. does anyone fixed this?

High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @svgr/webpack                                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > css-select >      │
│               │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754

High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano >               │
│               │ cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select >  │
│               │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754

Answer (score 0):

If you bother clicking the link

> Overview css-what before 5.0.1 does not ensure that attribute parsing
> has Linear Time Complexity relative to the size of the input.
>
> **Remediation** Upgrade to version 5.0.1 or later
>
> Resources CVE GitHub Advisory

I'm assuming you or one of your packages is still using css-what older version without the fix.

Comment: yes that is reason, it is used by optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano > │ │ │ cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select > │ │ │ css-what 


is there anyway i can override version in package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Though I had been getting the same issue on my reactjs application (NOT in React-native), but I believe how I resolved the issue might help you in some way.

My local system has 2 Node version. `nvm ls` results v11.0.0, v13.6.0.
Incase I execute `npm start` on `v13.6.0 I` always get the above said issue (`css-what Denial of Service vulnerability`).

I understand it's bcz of version mismatching in one of the `css-what` version used in between the hierarchies in react-scripts->css-assets-webpack-plugin->cssnano->cssnano-preset-default->postcss-svgo->svgo->css-select->css-what

In order to not let such version mis-matching in my app I used v11.0.0.
I executed `nvm use v11.0.0`
And then onwards `npm start` never gave such error. I even didn't have to do audit fix (though `audit fix --force` had never resolved my issue).